# Convert base64 PDF to base64 image file

Tags: node.js, pdf, base64, pdfkit

I have an application where i am creating a PDF using PDFKit npm module.

I have a use case where i am provided the base64 string of a pdf document that needs to be converted to an image, so i can then embed that into another PDF document using PDFKit.

I wish to do this in memory and not save any actual documents, i need to input a base64 string in PDF format and get one back in an image format.

How can i convert base64 string PDF to a base64 string image (png, jpg, etc) using javascript/node?